# Substitution with limits

Tags: calculus, limits

If we have a limit to solve, doesn't matter which, but $\lim_{x\to 0}\ln(\frac{1}{x})$ for example, is the substitution $t=\frac{1}{x}$ allowed? Because as $x\to 0$, $t\to DNE$? Because $\lim_{x\to 0^+}\frac{1}{x}=+\infty$ and $\lim_{x\to 0^-}\frac{1}{x}=-\infty$? Hence non sided limit is DNE

Comment: You can consider two cases one for $x\to0^+$ i.e RHL and then for LHL. And then proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Note that
$$\lim_{x\to0^+}f(x) = \lim_{t\to +\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right) \\ \lim_{x\to0^-}f(x) = \lim_{t\to -\infty}f\left(\frac{1}{t}\right)$$
Usually, the "infinity" without a sign means that the "infinities" with both signs are being dealt simultaneously; that is, $\infty = \pm \infty$. So, you can say $$x\to 0 \implies \frac{1}{x} \to \infty$$

Comment: I would say that usually (in real analysis) $\infty$ means $+\infty$.

Comment: @HansLundmark Our textbooks use that notation and this is why it should always be introduced before being used anywhere :)

Comment: @HansLundmark Also, I think $\infty = \pm \infty$ is more natural since most people usually write just $$\lim_{x\to\infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$$ to mean $$\lim_{x\to \pm\infty} \frac{1}{x} = 0$$

Comment: In complex analysis, it's standard to use just one “$\infty$” for all directions (and then it's not just along the real axis, of course). And some people might use that convention in real analysis too, but in my experience, it's much more common to say that $\infty=+\infty$, so I disagree with your claim about “most people”.

Comment: @HansLundmark Maybe I should have claimed "most people in my country" :)